# Spine.js - How to set up nested stacks

Tags: spine.js

I'm trying to set up nested stacks in Spine.js.

Although I copy-pasted the code that seems to work for others (https://gist.github.com/MikeSilvis/2839845) and adjusted the controller & model names it doesn't work.
**Both stacks get shown perfectly right**, there are no errors in the console either. But - if I don't fully misunderstand the usage of nested stacks - they are not nested within a root stack. Is there something that I have to add in the views?

**index.coffee:**

```
class App extends Spine.Controller

  constructor: ->
    super
    new Spine.SubStack
    Spine.Route.setup()

    @append(@groups = new App.Groups)
    @append(@people = new App.People)

class App.Root extends Spine.Stack
  $.fn.item = ->
    elementID   = $(@).data('id')
    elementID or= $(@).parents('[data-id]').data('id')
    Person.find(elementID)
  controllers:
    groups: App.Groups
    people: App.People

  routes:
    '/groups' : 'groups'
    '/people' : 'people'

  default: 'people'
  className: 'stack root'

class Spine.SubStack extends Spine.Stack

  constructor: ->
    for key,value of @routes
      console.log [key, value].join(" | ")
      do (key,value) =>
        @routes[key] = =>
          @active()
          @[value].active(arguments...)
    super

window.App = App
```

**in groups.coffee:**

```
class App.Groups extends Spine.SubStack
  controllers:
    index: Index
    edit:  Edit
    show:  Show
    new:   New

  routes:
    '/groups/new':      'new'
    '/groups/:id/edit': 'edit'
    '/groups/:id':      'show'
    '/groups':          'index'

  default: 'index'
  className: 'stack groups'
```

**in people.coffee:**

```
class App.People extends Spine.SubStack
  controllers:
    index: Index
    edit:  Edit
    show:  Show
    new:   New

  routes:
    '/people/new':      'new'
    '/people/:id/edit': 'edit'
    '/people/:id':      'show'
    '/people':          'index'

  default: 'index'
  className: 'stack people'
```

All routes are still working after adding this code, but there is no root stack.

Hopefully someone with little more experience than me can help me out of this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Without doing too much research, it seems like you should have a `new App.Root` or `extends App.Root` somewhere.  That could explain why your routes are working, but there is no root stack.